# Image processing:Segmentation

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I need to segment the disease part in the rice plant[brown spot disease,i have attached one image also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEDk7.jpg)
I am using hue component of HSV mode together with OTSU to segment the diseased part in cv2[resulted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N6H7.png),can anyone give me a general strategy in steps (even a code in python) to segment the diseased part accurately.
this is what i am trying.

```
img=cv2.imread('3.jpg')
img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v=cv2.split(img)
th=0
ret,out1=cv2.threshold(h,th,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
plt.imshow(out1,cmap='gray',interpolation='bicubic')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe this sounds rude, but I think you need to start with a text book on image processing. This is not a trivial problem, a single threshold will never do, and solving this problem is way more work than you can expect from an answer on SO.

Comment: You could start with Canny edge detection and reprocess the result. Looks like the diseased parts have quite defined edges due to the brown borders.